# Making timestamps out of Kafka Connect Single Message Transformer

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I am moving data from Kafka to Elasticsearch and using Kafka connects SMT and more specificly `TimeStampConverter` . I fiddled around some with it and couldnt get it to output a Timestamp format.

When I used types "Date", "Time" or "Timestamp" as the values for `transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type` I couldnt get data into Elasticsearch. It was only until I set the value "string" there that it outputs the values into elasticsearch as date data type. This unfortunately means that I can only get the value by accuracy of a day.

Here is the transformer configs:

```
   "transforms": "TimestampConverter",
   "transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
   "transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "UPDATED",
   "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "string"
```

Any known ways how to achieve this with more accurate timestamp? I tried all kinds of configurations alterin the `target.type`and `format` fields

The UPDATED value is epoch bigint